# How to make this paper - note like tcolorbox breakable?

Tags: tcolorbox, paper, break-box

I use frequently (with some modifications) in my papers the `marker tcolorbox`, its definition for reference can be found in site [tcolorbox.doc.s_main.sty](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/master/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.doc.s_main.sty) (search for `marker`). I have included this definition in my minimal working example below. I would like to modify it so it can take two or more pages, to be "breakable" in terms of `tcolorbox package`. Unfortunately, adding the option `breakable` it does not help as it keeps the folded right corner in all pages except the last one "uncut" and I would like to be all lower right corners cut OR all pages except the last one to be "unfolded" and "uncut". Here is what I succeeded so far.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}  
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\newtcolorbox{marker}[2][]{breakable,enhanced,adjusted    title=#2,fonttitle=\bfseries,colbacktitle=yellow!50,coltitle=black,titlerule=0.1pt  
    before skip balanced=2mm,after skip balanced=3mm,  
    boxrule=0.4pt,left=2mm,right=2mm,top=1mm,bottom=7mm,  
    colback=yellow!30,  
    colframe=yellow!20!black,    
    sharp corners,rounded corners=southeast,arc is angular,arc=9mm,  
    underlay={%  
        \path[fill=tcbcolback!80!black,scale=3] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);  
        \path[draw=tcbcolframe,shorten <=-0.05mm,shorten >=-0.05mm,scale=3]   ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);  
    },  
    drop fuzzy shadow,#1}  
\begin{document}  
    \begin{marker}{Title}  
        \lipsum[1-10]  
    \end{marker}  
\end{document}
```

As you can see in the first page the lower right corner is not like the last part. How can I make it breakable and only the last right corner to be folded OR on all pages all the right lower corners to be cut like the last part? In the above mwe I have added the option `breakable` which does not give me the desired result.

Comment: Please don't make your question rely on an external link that could break in the future. This is a Q&A site, so self-contained questions are important. Thank you.

Comment: No it is not relied on an external link, a have included the code which includes the definition of this tcolorbox. The link is only for reference.

Comment: OK, sorry. You do instruct at the beginning to look for "marker" in the linked document, so I misunderstood.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}  
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\newtcolorbox{marker}[2][]{%
    breakable, enhanced,
    adjusted title=#2, fonttitle=\bfseries, colbacktitle=yellow!50, 
    coltitle=black, titlerule=0.1pt,   
   before skip balanced=2mm, after skip balanced=3mm,  
   boxrule=0.4pt, left=2mm, right=2mm, top=1mm, bottom=7mm,  
   colback=yellow!30, colframe=yellow!20!black,    
   sharp corners, rounded corners=southeast, arc is angular, arc=9mm,  
   underlay unbroken and last ={%  
        \path[fill=tcbcolback!80!black,scale=3] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);  
        \path[draw=tcbcolframe, shorten <=-0.05mm, shorten >=-0.05mm, scale=3]   ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);  
    },  
    drop fuzzy shadow, #1}  
\begin{document}  

    \begin{marker}{Title}  
        \lipsum[1]  
    \end{marker}  

    \begin{marker}{Title}  
        \lipsum[1-10]  
    \end{marker}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exaclty what I wanted. I was working on the example of page 412 (version 5.1.1 24/06/2022) of tcolorbox manual. It seems that there is the solution but you catch me up. I was missing the `underlay unbroken and last` option. Thanks a lot!